# Volume check fail - magento 2 data migration delta step

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have successfully completed migrated data from Magento1-EE(1.12.0.2) to Magento2-EE(2.1.5). To migrate additional data from newer Magento1 database I am trying to use delta step of data migration tool.

I am facing **Volume check failed** error during migration with warning message **Mismatch of entities in the document**. I have set map.xml file previously to migrate bulk data using data step.

What should I need to check more to migrate additional data using delta step? Any help would be appreciated.